# Apache Camel Netty - Bind NIC

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I've to send a message over network using netty producer on machine A to netty consumer on machine B.

I have two NICs on machine A, and I want to use only the second. How can I set a Netty producer to bind the socket on the second NIC? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using *UDP*, you can use the option `networkInterface` to bind to a NIC by name. See the official [Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/netty.html#Netty-Options) for this.

> Consumer only. When using UDP then this option can be used to specify
>   a network interface by its name, such as eth0 to join a multicast
>   group.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for reply. I resolved using linux routing.